# 500 Error:expected "indent", but got "newline"

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
ration_enum={' ':' ','定性':'定性','定量':'定量'}
for val, key in ration_enum
if modi_type=='edit'&&key==common_index.ration
option(value='#{key}', selected) #{val}
else
option(value='#{key}') #{val}
```

expected "indent", but got "newline"

Comment: @JasonYang I'm not fluent in Chinese, unfortunately: can you translate this into English?

Comment: ration_enum={' ':' ','ration':'ration','quantitative':'quantitative'}

Comment: oh,sorry,i see some Chinese and i think you may a chinese

Comment: I am too careless to forget to change into English= =,Where are you from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing this is a [Jade template](http://jade-lang.com/)...

Jade follows the Python rule where whitespace matters, so you have to indent your code properly:

```
ration_enum={' ':' ','定性':'定性','定量':'定量'}
for val, key in ration_enum
    if medi_type == 'edit' && key == common_index.ration
        option(value='#{key}', selected) #{val}
    else
        option(value='#{key}') #{val}
```

Jade has *flexible* indentation in that you can choose whether to use tabs or spaces, as well as how many spaces. But, you have to be consistent in your choice throughout the template.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue for a different reason.

For the purposes of the examples I'm giving

```
 _ = [tab]
```

This is **invalid** Jade:

```
 div
 _ div
 _ _
 _ _ div
```

This is **valid** Jade:

```
 div
 _ div

 _ _ div
```

So basically make sure any trailing white space on empty new lines is deleted or your Jade won't compile.

[This sublime plugin](https://github.com/SublimeText/TrailingSpaces) will help automate the process :)